# A semicontinuous function discontinuous at an uncountable number of points?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

This is an exercise from *A second course on real functions*.

Do you have an example of a semicontinuous function defined on $[0,1]$ which is discontinuous at an uncountable number of points?

Comment: A characteristic function of a famous set.

Comment: It is even possible to make a stronger version of the statement that the set of discontinuity has a *positive Lebesgue measure*. Just take the indicator of a Cantor set on $[0,1]$ of positive measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indicator function on Cantor set, as suggested by @Daniel Fischer's comment.