# Discontinuities of upper semicontinuous function

Tags: continuity, semicontinuous-functions

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an upper semicontinuous function (USC), i.e. for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, the set $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) < \alpha \}$ is open.

What are the set of discontinuities of $f$? For $f = \chi_{[- \infty, 0)}$, its discontinuity is $x=0$. Hence, the set of discontinuities of an USC is finite. Do we have example such that set of discontinuities of an USC is countable or uncountable?

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443792/a-semicontinuous-function-discontinuous-at-an-uncountable-number-of-points) states that characteristic function of Cantor set has uncountable discontinuities. But there is no justification on why such function is upper semicontinuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, for a set $S\subseteq \Bbb R$, $$\{x\in\Bbb R\,:\,\chi_S(x)<\alpha\}=\begin{cases}\Bbb R&\text{if }\alpha>1\\\Bbb R\setminus S&\text{if }0<\alpha\le1\\\emptyset&\text{if }\alpha<0\end{cases}$$

an indicator function is USC if and only if $S$ is closed, and LSC if and only if $S$ is open.